# Logstash configuration reload

Tags: logstash

Is the Logstash configuration reloaded every time the agent is restarted? It doesn't seem to pick up my changes immediately (e.g. changed `type` value)

I'm running it with an embedded elasticsearch v.0.90.7 on Windows 7 and Kibana 3.

Thank you very much!

Regards,
Paul

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hot Reload is not yet supported. There is a [Issue](https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-227).

The logstash configuration is loaded at startup, so, if you kill your process (to restart it later), there is no reason why it does not work.

Comment: The issue you linked is overkill for @Paul's use case.  The issue is the java startup time -- on the system I'm working on today, it takes 13 seconds to start up.  Ideally the logstash process would follow the common Unix pattern and accept a HUP signal (`kill -HUP <pid>`) to trigger it to reload its configuration and rebuild the pipelines.

Answer (score 5):

Good news! Dynamic config reloading is currently scheduled for release with Logstash 2.3+(https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-lines-2016-02-09)! Just use `--reload-interval` or send a SIGHUP to reload the config!

Comment: Warning: In regards to Andrew's response, sending a SIGINT to the logstash process as of version 2.2 will terminate the process, not reload the configuration.

Comment: Apologies, my mistake with the versions here. We are targeting 2.3 for this feature which should be coming out shortly.  The signal will be SIGHUP not SIGINT. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be available in Logstash 5: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/reloading-config.html